# File in Use while trying to Clear Text File

Tags: c#

In my program I am loading a text files information into a rich text box. When the user clicks the clear button I want the files contents to be empty and display it again on the rich text box. However when I try to clear an error pops up that the file is already in use.

I am not sure of of what is going on with this, I have a suspicion it has to do with closing the stream reader or creating a new one. Either way I am not quite sure.

Does anyone have any thoughts of what is going on with this?

Code:

```
namespace FileLocationAutomation
{
    public partial class ViewLog : Form
    {
        public ViewLog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region Variables
        string str = "";
        #endregion 

        #region Ok Button
        private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Form Load
        private void ViewLog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //catch any exception
            try
            {
                //load the log thats kept on the users machine into the rich text object 
                StreamReader read = new StreamReader(GlobalVars.strLogPath);
                str = read.ReadToEnd();
                rtxtView.Text = str;
                read.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        #endregion 

        #region Clear Log
        //clear the log file and display it on the rich text box
        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader read = new StreamReader(GlobalVars.strLogPath);
                File.WriteAllText(GlobalVars.strLogPath, String.Empty);
                str = read.ReadToEnd();
                rtxtView.Text = str;
                read.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);               
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the static methods in the `File` class

Comment: Looks like you're opening the file with StreamReader, then trying to do a general file write. If you're clearing it out you don't need to read back an empty file.

Comment: I know you have `.Close()` on your file and technically I think that should be ok, but best if you wrap your `StreamReader` vars in a `using` statement to ensure `.Dispose()` is called.  See if it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to write to the file to clear it while still holding it open. The simplest change is to move the call to `File.WriteAllText(GlobalVars.strLogPath, String.Empty);` to after where you close the file, as follows:

```
 #region Clear Log
//clear the log file and display it on the rich text box
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        StreamReader read = new StreamReader(GlobalVars.strLogPath);
        str = read.ReadToEnd();
        rtxtView.Text = str;
        read.Close();

        File.WriteAllText(GlobalVars.strLogPath, String.Empty);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);               
    }
}
```

A better change would probably to use the static read method, since you're reading the whole file in one go there's no need to use the StreamReader.

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        rtxtView.Text = File.ReadAllText(GlobalVars.strLogPath);
        File.WriteAllText(GlobalVars.strLogPath, String.Empty);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);               
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the order he's doing things in the question your second suggestion is actually wrong. He wants to clear the file and set the textbox to be empty.

Comment: @Logarr I disagree: he says "When the user clicks the clear button I want the files contents to be empty and display it again on the rich text box." It's not very clearly worded, but it sounds like he wants to display the contents of the file and clear it. Maybe user3302467 can clear this up for us...

Comment: The third option worked the best. Except I switched around the rtxtView.Text ... to go after the File.Write... and it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure. Turns out the interpretation that @Logarr mentioned was correct. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is strictly here:

```
try
{
    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(GlobalVars.strLogPath);
    File.WriteAllText(GlobalVars.strLogPath, String.Empty);
    str = read.ReadToEnd();
    rtxtView.Text = str;
    read.Close();
}
```

Make it look like this:

```
try
{
    File.WriteAllText(GlobalVars.strLogPath, String.Empty);
    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(GlobalVars.strLogPath);
    str = read.ReadToEnd();
    rtxtView.Text = str;
    read.Close();
}
```

Or since reading a blank file back is useless, do it like this:

```
try
{
    File.WriteAllText(GlobalVars.strLogPath, String.Empty);
    rtxtView.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

enclose the `StreamReader` declaration in `using block {}`to make sure that it gets disposed.

Try This:

```
 using(StreamReader read = new StreamReader(GlobalVars.strLogPath))
 {
        str = read.ReadToEnd();
        rtxtView.Text = str;
 }
```

OR

```
rtxtView.Text = File.ReadAllText(GlobalVars.strLogPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change the order.

```
try
{
    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(GlobalVars.strLogPath);
    File.WriteAllText(GlobalVars.strLogPath, String.Empty);
    str = read.ReadToEnd();
    // close the stream first.
    read.Close();
    rtxtView.Text = str;
}
```